# Incorrect mpld3 plotting in log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I noticed a very puzzling behavior when plotting in mpld3. I did three things: 1. plot the data as is in linear scale. 2. plot the log10 of data on linear scale. 3. plot the original data on log scale. Plots 2 and 3 should look the same, but they don't. It appears the y axis is inverted in plot 3.

Option 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins, utils

x = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
y = [1, 10, 100, 1000]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y, s=25, c='orange')
#ax.scatter(np.log10(x), np.log10(y), s=25, c='orange')
#ax.set_xscale('log')
#ax.set_yscale('log')
plugins.connect(fig, plugins.MousePosition())
mpld3.show()
```

Option 2.

```
#ax.scatter(x, y, s=25, c='orange')
ax.scatter(np.log10(x), np.log10(y), s=25, c='orange')
#ax.set_xscale('log')
#ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Option 3.

```
ax.scatter(x, y, s=25, c='orange')
#ax.scatter(np.log10(x), np.log10(y), s=25, c='orange')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Am I missing something or can this be a bug? The JSON data included in the page appear to contain ylim and ydomain etc as expected, so I am very mystified how the graph got inverted.

Comment: Using some test data with `matplotlib` v 1.3.1 I get exactly as expected without any inversion. If possible can you provide an minimum working example which reproduces the error, e.g with some test data. Also check the `matplotlib` version.

Comment: I added more code. How do you check the matplotlib version? I installed it within past month, so I would expect it to be fairly up to date. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I imported matplotlib and printed matplotlib.__version__, which gives 1.3.1.

Comment: Okay I can confirm this is also occuring for me with `mpld3` version 0.2. Sorry hadn't spotted that you were using this. It seems to be switching the x and y axes around (try playing with the data to see this).

Comment: It doesn't look like the axes are being swapped, e.g. using x = [1, 100, 10000, 1000000]; y = [4, 8, 16, 32]. But the y axis inverted, and the values on the two axes do not match what you would expect (e.g. I would expect the points to line up with 0, 2, 4, and 6 on the x axis but they don't).

Comment: You are correct, perhaps raise an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3)

Comment: This bug is reported in the project issue tracker: https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/227

Answer (score 1):

One possible work around is to draw the points using plot instead of scatter. The bug seems to only be a problem with the scatter function. So instead of:

```
ax.scatter(x, y)
```

use this:

```
ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='')
```